# "I will never be alone with you." what does that mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> I will never be alone with you.

Does it mean *I want to be with you* or *I don't want to be with you*?

Comment: Can you include more context? Without context, it can actually mean two opposing things.

Comment: @catija can you give me example? unfotunately there is no context. Someone(we are non native speaker) asked the question. so I said it means B. But another say this sentence means that I will be with you so I'm no longer lonely. Is that right?

Comment: *I will never be alone with you* does not mean A or B (or C, in between, as in no opinion on the matter). The quoted sentence can be used as part of a context that includes either A or B (or C, neutral).

Comment: They are stating the **fact** that the two of you will never be alone together. They are not saying whether this fact makes them feel happy or sad. Therefore, there is no way to know whether or not they want to be alone with you. They are only saying that they wont be.

Comment: @Keiki yes... **but** *how* they say it, if it's said orally, can give you the context. It can be understood if it's said aloud.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can mean either:

- > Because of you, I will never be alone.

  This could be better re-written as "*With you, I will never be alone.*"
- > Whenever I am with you, other people will always be nearby; the two of us will never be alone together.

  Note that this does not indicate whether I *want* this to be the case. Compare two uses:

  > I want to tell you a secret in private, but your parents are always watching us. I will never be alone with you.
  >
  > I know that if no one is watching, you will try to rob me. To protect myself, I will never be alone with you.

Comment: For the "To protect myself" version, I would explain it as: `I will never put myself into a position where only you and I are together`

Comment: It can also mean the situation where the speaker will take great pains to ensure that the two of them are never alone.

Answer (score 0):

Without context or knowing which words received emphasis, apsillers' answer covers both A and B. However, rearranging the sentence could mean something else entirely:

> With you, I will never be (feel) alone.

"*[Never do I feel more alone than with other people](https://www.google.com/search?q=never%20do%20i%20feel%20more%20alnoe%20then%20with%20other%20people&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=never%20do%20i%20feel%20more%20alone%20than%20with%20other%20people&spell=1),* but with *you* it's different because of the connection we share."

Said from one companion to another, 'never *feeling* alone' is what they meant. Anyone else would be talking about the impossibility or their unwillingness to be alone with someone, literally.

Whichever way it's worded, it's still rather ambiguous. We have a written transcript of what they *said*. We'd need the context of their relationship to know what they *meant*.